# Segmentation fault - Strtok - Linux C

Tags: c, linux, strtok

I have been blinded on this "error". The function separates a command with its parameters from a string. I'm using strtok for this. Im pretty sure is something stupid,but I cant see it.
The function is:

```
int dataCommand(char command[], char *data[]){
    char *ch;
    printf("Split \"%s\"\n", command);
    ch = strtok(command, "_");
    int i = 0;
    data[i] = ch;
    printf("%s\n", data[i]);
    while (ch != NULL) {
        ch = strtok(NULL, "_");
        data[++i] = ch;
        printf("Valor ch Salida: %s\n", ch);
   }
   printf("dataCommand END");
   return 0;
}
```

The call for this function is:

```
char *data[MAX_PARAM]; //MAX_PARAM = 80
char command[] ="UMBR_Donostia_1_2";
dataCommand(command,data);
```

Result on screen:

```
Split "UMBR_Donostia_1_2"
UMBR
Valor ch Salida: Donostia
Valor ch Salida: 1
Valor ch Salida: 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have been investigating and most error i found was using a char * over strtok, so they were using a literal, but im using char[]. I dont know what else could be. Thanks.

Comment: It's probably crashing in `printf` because you're passing it a null pointer.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to help you find the problem?

Comment: @melpomene eliminating all printf, same happens.

Comment: @By-Jokese Run the code that I added and tell us your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My compiler's result for your program:

```
Split "UMBR_Donostia_1_2"
UMBR
Valor ch Salida: Donostia
Valor ch Salida: 1
Valor ch Salida: 2
Valor ch Salida: (null)
```

Clearly you are passing a null value to it.

[UPD1]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PARAM 80

int dataCommand(char command[], char *data[]){
    char *ch;
    printf("Split \"%s\"\n", command);
    int i = 0;
    ch = strtok(command, "_");
    while (ch != NULL) 
    {
        data[i++] = ch;
        printf("Valor ch Salida: %s\n", ch);
        ch = strtok(NULL, "_");
    }
   printf("dataCommand END");
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
  char *data[MAX_PARAM]; //MAX_PARAM = 80
  char command[] ="UMBR_Donostia_1_2";
  dataCommand(command,data);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe you have more modern compiler... but still you dont get "dataCommand END", why is that? and i dont get that result

Comment: Right, that was correct. my problem was with another part of the code that conflicted with this function. Will check the rest of the code. Thx. As the question was about that problem i close this.

Comment: So it means that our compilers are equally modern :D

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your loop, you're calling `strtok` to get the next token, but you're not checking it for NULL before doing anything with it.

Reformat to put the `strtok` at the end of the loop like so:

```
int dataCommand(char command[], char *data[]){
    char *ch;
    printf("Split \"%s\"\n", command);
    int i = 0;
    ch = strtok(command, "_");
    while (ch != NULL) {
        data[i++] = ch;
        printf("Valor ch Salida: %s\n", ch);
        ch = strtok(NULL, "_");
   }
   printf("dataCommand END");
   return 0;
}
```

Also note that some redundant code that was before the loop has been removed in favor of code in the loop.

Comment: You are right, dome reduntat code, but still getting Segmentation fault.

Comment: @By-Jokese The above code, along with the three lines you gave for the caller with `#define MAX_PARAM 80` compiles clean and runs fine, with no issues reported by valgrind.  The issue may be in your test code, so post that as an update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Call `strtok()` in the loop **after** you process the current token.

```
while (ch != NULL) {
    printf("Valor ch Salida: %s\n", ch);
    data[++i] = ch;
    ch = strtok(NULL, "_");
}
```

Since you called `strtok()` first, you were skipping the first token, and when you reached the end you were calling `printf()` with a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int
dataCommand(char *command,char *data[])
{
    char *ch;
    int i = 0;

    while (1) {
        ch = strtok(command, "_");
        command = NULL;

        if (ch == NULL)
            break;

        data[i++] = ch;
        printf("Valor ch Salida: %s\n", ch);
   }

   printf("dataCommand END\n");

   return 0;
}
```